# Declare a vector in a function call and pass it by reference

Tags: c++, vector

I'd like to declare a `vector` this way:

```
myFunction(new std::vector<stuff>{});
```

With the `vector` passed as a reference:

```
void myFunction(const std::vector<stuff> &myVec);
```

Comment: Who willl delete the vector?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to `new` the argument (which in any case returns a pointer, not an lvalue). You can simply pass a temporary:

```
myFunction(std::vector<stuff>{});
```

A temporary can bind to a `const` lvalue reference.

Answer (score 0):

If the parameter is optional, you can simply declare the function as

`void myFunction(const std::vector<stuff>& myVec = std::vector<stuff>{});`

Then, you can call it like `myFunction()` when the default argument is fine.